# Make Ubuntu first option when dual booting

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed. When rebooting I always have to choose between those 2.How can i make Ubuntu become the first option when i boot my computer?

Comment: What **Ubuntu** version?  For 12.04, this should already be the default behavior. Do you want the choice, or delay to be removed also?

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

`0` is now set for Windows 7, change it to the number associated with Ubuntu

Another way is to use ***Grub Customizer***.  If you don't have it you can install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

then find this line (mostly line Number 13)

```
set default="0"
```

in set default if you place **0** it will boot to First title you have in grub.cfg and for **1** its boot to 2nd title .

so for your case it should be **0**.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the use of EasyBCD to edit the Windows boot loader, may well be a feasible answer when the  traditional BIOS and MBR approach to starting up your PC is in use. When the computer in use has been shipped with UFEI firmware and boot manger, as is increasingly the case, then using EasyBCD is (by their own admission) not really appropriate.

One of the alternatives offered (by EasyBCD) is to use a virtual machine. That taken together with another alternative given, which involves Grub2 EFI wresting control from MS UEFI, booting Linux first and ultimately chainloading NTLDR to boot into windows, I’m inclined to get overwhelmed by the unnecessary complexity of it all and say “how do I now make this computer entirely Ubuntu”.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are asking (Windows for the Default), I'll assume that you are using Wubi.

To edit the Windows Bootloader, install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).  It is a free tool (you'll have to click the "Register" Link at the bottom, although you don't need to register) that allows you to modify the Windows BootLoader in a pain-free way.

Next, launch EasyBCD.  Then go to the **Edit Boot Menu** part, click on the **Yes** tickbox beside Ubuntu, then click on **Save Settings**.  You are Done!

[image]