# VLC media player suddenlly stopped playing .m2ts files?

Tags: vlc

I'm new to ubuntu and I am using vlc player 
suddenly it stopped playing m2ts files
all other files are ok except for m2ts

I think this happened after I executed the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

from this link:

[Make Ubuntu first option when dual booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157667/make-ubuntu-first-option-when-dual-booting)

any help to fix this...

Comment: tried that but nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem is.
it is because there is a subtitle file in the same directory of the .m2ts file.
I placed it but I never thought that this might be the problem so I didn't mentioned it.
I removed the subtitle and the file worked correctly, I placed the file again and it stopped working.
ridiculous.

Comment: It's 2022, and I just got into identical issue! :D Funny how this wasn't fixed since 8 years…